# Slug Field in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a model class that has a **Title** field. Now I want to generate **Slug** from the **Title** field. How shall that be done?

Comment: You should provide more details regarding the context

Comment: I assume you could use [**`slugify()`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/utils/#django.utils.text.slugify) function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the [`django.utils.text.slugify`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/utils/#django.utils.text.slugify) method.  If you want to use it you can simple call `slugify()` on your title.  In a serializer you might want to use it like so:

```
from django.utils.text import slugify

class ExampleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    title_slug = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_title_slug(self, instance):
        return slugify(instance.title)

    class Meta:
        model = Example
        fields = ("title_slug", )
```

Comment: `SerializerMethodField` should be `read_only` else it may create problems while object creation. Also, the **`instance`** argument mostly not available while creation

Comment: [`SerializerMethodField` is implicitly `read_only`](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/fields.py#L1835).  This example solution doesn't save the slugified title, it just provides another field with the slugified title of an instance, saved or not.  It will work after object creation, because the `serializer.data` attribute will be returned after the instance is saved.